# How to make 4 rectangle boxes fit to the screen in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, padding, brackets, margins

I have a design(its on desktop view) as shown below which I am trying to replicate in Bootstrap 3.[image]In the design, the 4 boxes are placed at the center with some spacing on left and right (I am assuming I have to put margin-left and margin-right in my CSS to get that spacing). On hover, every box background color is #F4F4F4.

At this moment, this is what I have made on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pawkxmbj/1/embedded/result/). In it, every box(eg: back-end, front-end, etc) is covering 50% of the screen size as I am using col-lg-6 class

In the fiddle, I can see margin-left and margin-right but for some reasons I can't see it (margin-left and margin-right) on my computer. The tool which I am using to make a webpage is Brackets.

I am wondering, how I can bring the boxes at the center exactly in the design with some spacing at left and right with hover on boxes. Also, do I need to use other Bootstrap class to get it done ?

The CSS code which I am using is:

```
#front-end:hover {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

#back-end:hover {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

#graphics-designer:hover {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

#sales:hover {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

#back-end h3 {
    color: blue
}

#front-end h3 {
    color: blue
}

#graphics-designer h3 {
    color: blue
}

#sales h3 {
    color: blue
}

.job-openings #back-end {
    text-align: center;
}

.job-openings #front-end {
    text-align: center;
}

.job-openings #graphics-designer {
    text-align: center;
}

.job-openings #sales {
    text-align: center;
}

.job-openings h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    color: #444444;
}

.job-openings .container {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: You are required to show your markup here, not a third party site which can change or disappear helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: @Rob My markup is in fiddle. Please check the fiddle.

Comment: To repeat: you are a are required to post your markup here, not a third party site. [mcve]

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that the code in your fiddle is doing what you want? There is no point in showing us an example and code that *works* because there is no problem there for us to help you find! As you have code that works, the problem is obviously with something else in your site that you have not shown us. We cannot help if we cannot see the issue and code that actually has the problem.

Comment: You could give the "container" and extra classname with a max-width?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, is this what you are searching for..

try changing the col-lg-6 to col-lg-5 / col-lg-4 as per your requirement for all the divisions and then add the col-lg-offset-1 / col-lg-offset-2 for the first item in the row for space in the front.